# Pour s'adresser à des filles on dit : vous êtes sures ?

Tags: genre, accord

Je me demande s'il doit y avoir accord ou pas, si "sûr" devrait prendre la forme de "sûres"… c'est quelque chose que je n'ai jamais vu mais je me demande.

Donc :

> vous êtes sûr

ou bien

> vous êtes sures

pour s'adresser à des filles ?

Answer (score 7):

Il faut faire l'accord de l'attribut du sujet avec le verbe être. La phrase est donc :

> Vous êtes sûres ?

voire même :

> Êtes-vous sûres ?

Answer (score 2):

Comme dit par M42 l'accord en genre et en nombre de l'attribut avec le sujet du verbe être se fait bien obligatoirement, donc si *vous* représente plusieurs choses ou personnes de genre féminin on met *es* à à la fin de l'adjectif.

Il faudrait quand même noter que les [rectifications orthographiques](http://www.orthographe-recommandee.info/regles4.htm) du français de 1990 autorise, au féminin et/ou au pluriel, l'absence de l'accent circonflexe présent au masculin sur le mot « sûr » (pour le distinguer à la fois de la préposition « sur » et de l'adjectif « sur » (synonyme de *acide*). Les deux orthographes, *sûr(e)s* et *sures* sont autorisées dans la mesure où « aucune des deux graphies  ne peut être tenue pour fautive » ; par contre au sein d'un même texte il est recommandé d'adopter une même orthographe (l'ancienne ou la nouvelle) et de ne pas changer en cours de rédaction, donc il faudrait trancher entre l'intitulé de la question :

> Pour s'adresser à des filles on dit : vous êtes sures ? (nouvelle  graphie)

et le déroulé de la question :

> Êtes-vous sûres ? (ancienne graphie)

Comment: Je ne comprends pas le second paragraphe et le reste de la réponse. L'omission de l'accent, généralement recommandée par la réforme, n'est-elle pas justement proscrite dans ce cas à cause de la confusion possible avec l'adjectif « sur » ?

Comment: @Relaxed Avant la réforme de 1990 l'accent circonflexe était obligatoire sur toutes les formes de l'adjectif *sûr* (voulant dire *certain*). La réforme de 1990 ne conserve l'accent que sur le masculin et le rend optionnel pour le féminin et le pluriel. Et ma remarque portait sur le fait que dans la question le mot était écrit une fois « sûres » et une fois « sures ». De façon générale il est recommandé dans un même texte d'opter pour l'application ou non de l'orthographe réformée et de s'y tenir, surtout pour un même mot.

Comment: Oui, tout ça était déjà clair pour moi, il m'a simplement semblé que le paragraphe suggérait justement l'inverse, c'est-à-dire que l'accent devenait optionel au masculin à cause de la confusion, ce qui n'a pas beaucoup de sens… Il faudrait au minimum une virgule dans la première phrase du deuxième paragraphe, probablement une nouvelle référence à la version féminine, sinon c'est difficilement compréhensible.

Comment: @Relaxed j'ai reformulé les deux phrases, car effectivement le but c'est d'être compris. Merci.